# Почему шрифты не отображаются WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Я хочу в программе использовать шрифты "Roboto", добавил их в ресурсы, обозначаю их в FontFamily
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в конструкторе они не отображаются.
А вот если скомпилировать программу, то все ок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать так, чтоб эти шрифты отображались в конструкторе?

Comment: Что такое конструктор? Дизайнер что ли?

Comment: Это может быть баг визуального дизайнера, мало ли. В дизайнере вообще куча багов. Если на работу программы это не влияет, то всё хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

У меня в приложении в папке ObjectControls лежит шрифт Disoluta-font-FFP.ttf установленный в Resource. Подключаю я его по имени шрифта. Всё работает на 100%.

```
    <TextBlock FontSize="40" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/ObjectControls/#Disoluta FFP"/>
```

Ссыль на аналогичный вопрос [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it)

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем дело.
Шрифты со свойством "Font embeddability = Editable" отображаются в конструкторе, а любые другие нет.
Т.к. у меня файл шрифтов со свойством "Font embeddability = Installable" то они не отображаются.

Answer (score 0):

Была проблема, парился как шрифт загнать в вэпэфэ, оказалось, что в сорсе надо прописывать Family Name шрифта, а не Full Name или, не дай бох, название файла шрифта. К примеру, есть пиздатый шрифт Sui Generis Rg ((c) Typodermic Fonts. Фсяхуйня ...), имя файла - sui generis rg.ttf, полное имя - SuiGenerisRg-Regular, которое светят нэкоторые фонтвьюверы. Так вот, чтобы эта падла хавалась дизайнером WPF, необходимо прописать (одна из азбук):

<FontFamily x:Key="КагУгодноKey">pack://application:,,,/../../fonts/#Sui Generis Rg</FontFamily>